# dynamic dependent dropdown with laravel 5.4

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I'm using the dynamic dependent dropdown with laravel 5.4 it works fine in local machine but when I put it on hosting and get accessed by many users it takes too long to get the second dropdown.

Fopm.php:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
 {!! Form::label('id_country',trans('Country').":",['class' => 'labels']) !!}
 {!! Form::select('id_country',['' => '...'] +$countries->toArray(),Input::get('id_country'),['class' => 'js-example-basic-single form-control select2_country']) !!}
</div>
<div class="form-group  col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
 {!! Form::label('id_city',trans('City').":",['class' => 'labels']) !!}
 {!! Form::select('id_city',['' => '...']+$cities->toArray(),Input::get('id_city'),['class' => 'js-example-basic-single form-control select2_city']) !!}
</div>
```

script.php:

```
sw = $('.select2_country').select2({
        placeholder: "Sélectionner",
        allowClear: true
    });
 sw.on("change", function (e) {
        id = $(this).select2('data')[0].id;
        $('.select2_city').val(null).trigger('change');
        $('.select2_city').select2({
            placeholder: "selectionner",
            allowClear: true,
            ajax: {
                url: '/api/caneva/cities?id=' + id
            }
        });

  });
  $('.select2_city').select2({
        placeholder: "selectionner",
        allowClear: true,
  });
```

Controller.php:

```
public function cities(SearchRequest $request)
{
    $id = $request->input('id');
    $city= DB::table('city')->select('libelle_city as text', 'id as id')
        ->where('id_country', '=', $id)
        ->get();
    return response()->json([
        'results' => $city
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Add index to `id_country` column, or make sure it is a foreign key

Comment: i already did it

Comment: Have you pinpointed if it's a slow database response, or slow rendering in the browser?